# React+Express: Getting error ECONNREFUSED when trying to grab data with fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Getting back into node but I'm having trouble connecting my front (React) and back (Node/Express). I went through [David Ceddia](https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/)'s article on his site and it works, 100% works with his example.

When trying to transfer this same logic into my own app I'm getting

`Proxy error: Could not proxy request /users from localhost:3000 to http://localhost/3001.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).`

Naturally, I found the section labeled `ECONNREFUSED` and it says

`ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host.`

So the connection is refused, but I can't figure out why.

### BACKEND

**users.js** (page we are requesting information from)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // Comment out this line:
  //res.send('respond with a resource');

  // And insert something like this instead:
  res.json([{
    id: 1,
    username: "samsepi0l"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    username: "D0loresH4ze"
  }]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

### FRONT

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shinyspork",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-jss": "^8.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost/3001"
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = { users: [] }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {this.state.users.map(user =>
          <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `"proxy": "http://localhost/3001"` - this should be `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` (colon instead of last slash).

Comment: This should be the answer ^^